# What does this mean: body[data-page~='hello'], in CSS3?

Tags: css, css-selectors

In CSS3, what is the difference between:

```
body[data-page~='hello'] {

}
```

and

```
body[data-page='hello'] {

}
```

I have seen that the ~ is known as the general sibling combinator, http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/ but I don't understand it in the context above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [CSS3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors):

> `[att=val]`: Represents an element with the `att` attribute whose value is exactly "val".
>
> `[att~=val]`: Represents an element with the `att` attribute whose value is a [whitespace](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#whitespace)-separated list of words, one of which is exactly "val". If "val" contains whitespace, it will never represent anything (since the words are *separated* by spaces). Also if "val" is the empty string, it will never represent anything.

Thus `<body data-page="hello world">` will be matched by the first rule but not the second.

Comment: Also note, as evidenced by the link to an older specification, that these selectors are not new to CSS3 (while the general sibling combinator `~` is new). The up to date specification is here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors